# angular service not work as singleton

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

Angular doc states:

```
Angular services are singletons
```

I want to use the angular service as singleton, so I can access the logged-in user data every where in my application. but the serivce does not seem to return the same data, here is my codes.

**Service**:

```
angular.module("myapp", [])

.service("identity", function (){
    this.token = null;
    this.user = null;
});
```

**Facotry**:

```
.factory("authentication", function (identity, config, $http, $cookieStore) {
var authentication = {};

authentication.login =  function (email, password, remember) {
    var p=$http.post(config.baseUrl+"api/","email="+email+"&password="+password);

    return p.then(function (response) {
            identity= response.data;

            if (remember) {
                $cookieStore.put("identity", identity);
            }
        });
};

authentication.isAuthenticated = function () {
    if (!identity.token) {
        //try the cookie
        identity = $cookieStore.get("identity") || {};
    }
    console.log(identity) // {token: 23832943, user: {name: something}}
    return !!identity.token;
};

return authentication;
});
```

**controller**:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($state, $scope, authentication, identity) {

    var user = $scope.user = {};

    $scope.login = function () {
        authentication.login(user.email, user.password, user.remember)
        .then(function () {
            if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                console.log(identity); // {token:null, user: null}
                $state.transitionTo("dashboard");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

The identity is injected to both authentication and controller. But the first console logs the correct user data, while the second console just logs the same data as initially defined. If the service is singleton as stated, I would expect two identity returns the same data. What am I doing wrong here?. any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `authentication` service change

```
identity= response.data;
```

to

```
identity.token=response.data.token;
identity.user=response.data.user;
```

and things should work.

Basically what you are doing is replacing the `identity` object reference.

Comment: a... you save me, man. have spent a few hours...thanks a million. :)